# Problems with referencing nested enumerate blocks

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I have a set of nested *enumerate* environment as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),ref=(\alph*),align=left]
  \item \label{first item}
     some notes for first item
  \item  \label{second item}
     The following are sub items
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph{enumi}.\roman*),ref(\roman*),align=left] 
      \item \label{item b.i}

      \item \label{item b.ii}

      \item \label{item b.iii}

      \item \label{item b.iv}

    \end{enumerate}

 \end{enumerate}
```

Late on when I refer with \ref{item b.iii} I get (c), which does not exist.

I cannot understand this anomaly and I would appreciate any help in this regard.

With my regards and plenty of thanks in advance,

partha

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I do not have this behaviour, after I've corrected your code (for the nested list)  from `ref(\roman*)` to the correct `ref=(\roman*)t`.

Comment: Please post compilable code. Your example will be especially frustrating to users new to LaTeX, since `enumerate` is defined in the kernel, but not with the definition you're using. That is, you've redefined it (probably by loading some package or some non-standard class).

Comment: You are definitely missing an `=` in `ref(\roman*)`, it should read `ref=(\roman*)`. With the `=` everything works fine. Without the `=` I get many errors and then if I force the compilation '(b.iii)'. If adding the `=` does not help you, please show us a full example of your code (an [MWE (link)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)), so that we can reproduce the problem without guessing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes it becomes difficult to find ones own mistake! The ref(\roman*) was the mistake!!!